# Adjust the color distribution on legend bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code is as follows:

```
ggplot(data=sim_mat_mel,aes(x=min,y=value,group=variable,color=threep)) + geom_line(show.legend = T) + 
  scale_color_gradientn("Three Point Percentage",labels=sam_data1$player2,breaks = sam_data1$threepper,limits=c(38.7,42.7),colors = rainbow(2,start = 3/6,end=0)) + 
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(3.6,"cm"),legend.text = element_text(face = "plain")) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

sam_data1 is a dataset as follows:

```
  threepper        player2
1  42.63791    Kyle Korver
2  41.34267     Steve Nash
3  39.71767 Anthony Parker
4  39.00147    Brent Barry
5  39.37482    Bruce Bowen
6  42.16895  Stephen Curry
```

And sim_mat_mel is as follows:

```
  min    variable     value  threep
1   1 Danny Ainge  4.999561 37.5615
2   2 Danny Ainge  7.241533 37.5615
3   3 Danny Ainge  9.412191 37.5615
4   4 Danny Ainge 11.511534 37.5615
5   5 Danny Ainge 13.539561 37.5615
6   6 Danny Ainge 15.496274 37.5615
```

The output of my code is : 
[image]

The problem is that the legend label overlaps with each other but there is a large space in the middle of the legend bar. So I think a method to do it is adjust the color distribution of the legend bar?

Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: Do you want a categorical legend? You're mapping a continuous variable to color, so the root problem isn't really that "there's a large gap in the legend bar" but that *there's a large gap in your data*.

Comment: You set your range to cover 38.7 to 42.7, a range of 4. But you don't have any data points between Parker (39.7) and Nash (41.3), a range of 1.6. So 1.6 / 4 = 40% of your scale has no data points.

Comment: Yeah that’s the case, I think maybe I should rescale the original data?

Comment: Alternatively as Gregor mentioned you could have a categorical legend which might look like 1 color per name. Some examples: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Comment: To "reduce" the gap you could just change the limits. I.e. change `limits=c(38.7,42.7)` to something like `limits=c(30,50)`

Comment: I have no idea what your data is, but rescaling in a linear way will preserve the gap. Rescaling in a non-linear way seems like fudging the numbers. If the gap is really there, I would assume it's meaningful and should be kept. If Nash, Curry, and Korver are really that much better than the others, why would you want to make it look like they're about the same?

Comment: You are right, but another problem is how I should reduce the overlapping of the labels ?

Comment: I have tried reduce the legend text size, but it is really small for the readers this way